# Question reg. Parallel activity in workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Currently I see the parallel activity in WF 4.0 get completed either both the branches are completed or a certain condition is met but the activity I'm looking for should behave like this if any of the branch is completed the control has to transfer to the following activity without cancelling the other branch activity. Is there any activity in WF 4.0 should satisfy this need? or I have to create a custom activity for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no activity that does this. The Parallel waits for all banches to complete or the CompletionCondition return true but then other branches a canceled as you describe.

What should happen to the other branches when the first is finished? They are scheduled so you have to do something with them or the scheduler will not see the "Parallel" activity as finished. That remains true even if you create your own activity.

Comment: if one branch is completed is it possible to run the other branch in different thread without cancelling it.

Comment: WF is not multi threaded. The thread used will change but there is never more than a single thread used for a single workflow instance.

Comment: That clarifies my doubt. Thanks.